# Is the empty set a subset of itself?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, definition

Sorry, but I don't think I can know, since it's a definition. Please tell me. I don't think that $0=\emptyset\,$, since I distinguish between empty set and the value $0$. Do all sets, even the empty set, have infinite emptiness e.g. do all sets, including the empty set, contain infinitely many empty sets?

Comment: Yes, but not a proper subset.

Comment: You refer to _the_ empty set, suggesting that you already know that there is a _unique_ set that is empty, so what do you mean by "contain infinitely many empty sets"?

Comment: @TrevorWilson Since set members should be unique there can be only one empty subset for every set. I was thinking something like `{}∈{}∈{}∈{}∈{}∈{}∈...` that you can always get a new empty set.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Empty set does not belong to empty set](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302064/empty-set-does-not-belong-to-empty-set)

Comment: Oops, I thought this was a duplicate, but I did not look closely enough. Unfortunately it seems I cannot un-vote to close :-(

Comment: @NickRosencrantz Regarding your last comment, $\emptyset \notin \emptyset$, because for all $x$ we have $x \notin \emptyset$ by the definition of $\emptyset$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen The link helped, thank you. ∅∉∅ and {}∉{} I'm now not absolutely sure which is which from the 2: `∅` and `{}` but I think that ∅∉∅ and {}∉{} while `{}⊂{}⊂{}⊂{}...`(?)

Comment: One has $\emptyset=\{\}$, it is just a shorthand. And indeed $\emptyset\notin\emptyset$ but $\emptyset\subseteq\emptyset$. And there is no point in making long chains, saying $\emptyset\subseteq\emptyset\subseteq\emptyset\subseteq\emptyset$ is as pointless as saying $2\leq2\leq2\leq2$.

Comment: Related: [Is {∅} a subset of {{∅}}?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/491465/121411)  and  [Is ∅∈∅ or ∅⊆∅?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/51752/121411)

Comment: It seems to be a difference between the set {} and the subset. If the empty set has a subset then it is not "empty" because the cardinality is 1 isn't it?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

There is only one empty set.  It is a subset of every set, including itself.  Each set only includes it once as a subset, not an infinite number of times.

Comment: I guess it is a stupid question, but what is a set which includes any set more than 1 time ?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis:   A [multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) can include multiple copies of elements.  Not a stupid question at all.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis That is a good question. Thank you for asking. Never heard of that before.

Comment: Then could not one make a multiset containing multiple copies of the empty set? 
M = {Ø, Ø} ?

Comment: @DionSilverman:  yes, you can.  A multiset can contain multiple copies of any element.  The empty set is not at all special here.

Comment: The empty set, $\emptyset = \{\}$, has $\emptyset$ as a subset of itself once. What about the set $S = \{\emptyset\} = \{\{\}\}$? How many times does $S$ have $\emptyset$ as a subset of itself? Once? Twice?

Comment: @joseville:  sets can only contain things once, so it doesn't make sense to ask how many times $S$ contains the empty set.  $S$ has only one subset that is the empty set.  It also has one subset that is $S$ itself.  That one is not the empty set.

Comment: @RossMillikan, thanks. Just want to point out that I'm strictly differentiating between **contains $x$** and **has $x$ as a subset**. As some other comments point out, it's possible for $x \notin S$ whilst still having $x \subset S$ (example, $\emptyset \notin \emptyset$, whilst $\emptyset \subset \emptyset$). So asking "how many times **$S$ contains $\emptyset$**?" is different than asking "how many times **$S$ has $\emptyset$ as a subset**?".

Comment: Now that I think about it, $S = \{\emptyset\}$ means $\emptyset \in S$, $\emptyset \subset S$, and $\{\emptyset\} \subset S$.

Comment: @joseville:  yes to the last.  That is spot on.

Answer (score 13):

> Let $A$ and $B$ be sets.  If every element $a\in A$ is also an element of $B$, then $A\subseteq B$.

Flip that around and you get

> If $A\not\subseteq B$, then there exists some element $x\in A$ such that $x\notin B$.

If $A$ is the empty set, there are no $x$s in $A$, so in particular there are no $x$s in $A$ that are not in $B$. Thus $A\not\subseteq B$ can't be true. Furthermore, note that we haven't used any property of $B$ in the previous line, so this applies to every set $B$, including $B=\emptyset$.

(From a wider standpoint, you can think of the empty set as the set for which $x\in \emptyset\implies P$ is true for every statement $P$.  For example, every $x$ in the empty set is orange; also, every $x$ in the emptyset is not orange.  There is no contradiction in either of these statements because there are no $x$'s which could provide counterexamples.)

Answer (score 6):

The empty set is subset of the empty set, as every element of the empty set is an element of the empty set. But $0$ is not in the empty set.

$A \subseteq B$ when $x\in A \implies x\in B$. As $x\in A \iff x\in A$ we see that $A \subseteq A$ is always true, when $A$ is a set.

A value is a value not a set, sometimes $0$ is defined as the empty set but then $0$ is the empty set and not the number.

This happens for example in category theory, as you are only interested in abstract sets, and all sets of the same cardinality are in a sense the same, you just title finite sets by their cardinality.

Answer (score 6):

*Any* set is a subset of itself. Let be
$$A=\{x\,\vert\,\varphi(x)\}.$$
As
$$\varphi(x)\implies \varphi(x),$$
we have
$$A\subseteq A.$$

Answer (score 3):

Because the [reflexivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation#Examples) of $\subseteq$, for all $A$ set $A \subseteq A$ is true. For $A = \emptyset$ we have that $\emptyset \subseteq \emptyset$, so the empty set is a subset of itself.

Answer (score 2):

The intersection of two sets is a subset of each of the original sets. So if $\phi$ is empty set and A is any set then $ \phi\cap A $ is $\phi$ which means $\phi$ is subset of A(which is any set) and $\phi$ is a subset of $\phi$ which implies empty set is subset of itself.

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of subset this question means:
Is every element of the empty set a member of the empty set?
The answer must be yes, since the empty set doesn't contain any elements.

Answer (score -1):

An empty subset can be selected from any set, including the empty set itself, using selection criteria that cannot be satisfied, e.g. selecting those elements $x$ such that $x\neq x$.

See my formal proof (in DC Proof format) at: http://dcproof.com/ExistenseOfNullSet.htm

There is only one empty set. If $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are empty sets, then $\ \phi_1 = \phi_2$.

See my formal proof (in DC Proof format) at: http://dcproof.com/UniquenessOfNullSet.htm

---

**Edit**: For any set $X$ we can select an empty subset $S$ such that:

$\forall a:[a\in S\iff a\in X\land a\neq a]$

or

$\forall a:[a\in S\iff a\in X\land a\notin X]$

Comment: That is correct. Thanks.