# Is $\{\emptyset\}$ a subset of $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\{\emptyset\}$ is a set containing the empty set. Is $\{\emptyset\}$ a subset of $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$?

My hypothesis is yes by looking at the form of "the superset $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$" which contains "the subset $\{\emptyset\}$".

Comment: No, there is only one element {0} in {{0}}

Comment: Is every element of the first set also an element of the last set?

Comment: What you are really noticing when you look at the form is that "the set $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$" contains the *element* $\{\emptyset\}$.  $\{\emptyset\}$ is an element of $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$, not a subset of it.

Answer (score 43):

It's easier to just replace everything by variables, then it's clearer.

Set $a=\varnothing, b=\{\varnothing\}=\{a\}$ and $c=\{\{\varnothing\}\}=\{\{a\}\}=\{b\}$.

Now the question is whether or not $\{a\}\subseteq\{b\}$. But since $a\neq b$, it's easy to see that the answer is negative.

Comment: I would add for all clarity that $a\neq b$ follows from the facts that $\emptyset\in b$ while $\emptyset\notin a$. But the important step is indeed to reduce the question to whether $a=b$ or not.

Comment: Marc, thank you for the excellent comment!

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen That would be called **assuming the conclusion**. The point is to prove that $\emptyset \notin a$, $\emptyset \in b$, and if you assume that to show that $a\ne b$, that defeats the whole point of making the second statement at all.

Comment: @AJMansfield: I don't see what you could have given you the conclusion that I assumed anything. I just indicated that one can justify $a\neq b$ by pointing at an element of $b\setminus a$. One could go further and explain why $\emptyset\in a$ and $\emptyset\notin b$ by applying the defintion of $a,b$ respectively. But nowhere is there an assumption.

Comment: My problem with this answer is that a is a subset of b, which in turn is a subset of c. Isn't it true that if a set contains a subset, all elements of that subset are in the set?

Comment: @Max: Yes, but I don't see why this is a problem here. The singleton $\{x\}$ (regardless to what $x$ is) has exactly one element, $x$.

Comment: Because then it becomes really inconvenient. For example, say you want to group two parts of a set into two subsets. But as soon as you do that, all elements in those subsets suddenly stop belonging to the original set? Dealing with sets in this manner becomes almost impossible in real life situations.

Comment: @Max: You need to distinguish between subsets and elements. That's the whole point of this question. Real life analogies will only take you so far, stick to definitions instead.

Answer (score 28):

No, $\emptyset \in \{\emptyset\}$ but $\emptyset \notin \{\{\emptyset\}\}$.

Comment: @Neil I don't think so. It state: "Is $\{\emptyset\}$ a subset of $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$?"

Comment: Wow! 6 upvotes for this!

Comment: William, there were over a 140 upvotes to Mariano's decomposition of $\pi$ into decimal digits, and over 200 (250?) to the infamous $\sf W$. What's 8 votes? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila, agreed, voting behavior on this site is pretty crazy. To quality of an answer is, in many ways, orthogonal to the number of votes it attracts (although positively related to its overall rank).

Comment: @user18921: I wouldn't say orthogonal. But the deviation of $|\text{votes}-\text{quality}|$ from the mean is fairly high.

Comment: @AsafKaragila What is 'the infamous W'?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I would agree with that.

Comment: @jwg: It was an answer consisting nothing more of the letter $\sf W$ illustrating the graph of a function which is continuous and differentiable everywhere except three points. It was given by one of the members which have [at this time] more reputation than me. Surely that would be enough for you to find it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila What's the infamous $\sf W$?

Comment: @MyUserIsThis: Read the last comment before yours.

Comment: The infamous $W$: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74347/construct-a-function-which-is-continuous-in-1-5-but-not-differentiable-at-2/74383#74383

Comment: Shouldn't we call it the nowfamous $W$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Wow, I'd never seen that... LOL

Comment: I think this is an accurate answer, though potentially misleading. Following the definition, the empty set is an element of his first set. That element is not in his second set, so his first set is not a subset of his second set.

Answer (score 19):

For such abstract questions, it is important that you stick to the **definitions** of the involved notions.

By *definition*, $A$ is a subset of $B$ if every element contained in $A$ is also contained in $B$.

Now we look at $A = \{\emptyset\}$ and $B = \{\{\emptyset\}\}$.
$A$ has exactly one element, namely $\emptyset$.
This is not an element of $B$, since the only element of $B$ is $\{\emptyset\}$ and $\emptyset \neq \{\emptyset\}$ (see below).
So $A$ is not a subset of $B$.

Why $\emptyset \neq \{\emptyset\}$?
By *definition*, two sets are equal if they contain the same elements. However, $\emptyset$ is the empty set without any element, but $\{\emptyset\}$ is a $1$-element set with the element $\emptyset$.

Comment: They're often interchangeable, but can I suggest "every" rather than "any" in the first definition (so that "…if every element contained in $A$…)?  In this case it's (to me, anyway) a little to easy to read it as "some" (as we might in "$A$ and $B$ have a common factor if any factor of $A$ is also a factor of $B$).

Comment: That said, +1 because this answer appeals to the definitions of subset and set equality, which I find makes this clearer than the currently highest upvoted answer.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: Thanks! I agree with your suggestion on "any" and "every" and modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

{{∅}} has only one element, namely {∅}, it implies there are only the two trivial subsets, {{∅}} which contains all elements and ∅ which contains none.

formally all subsets of {{∅}}

{{∅}}⊆{{∅}}
∅⊆{{∅}}

Answer (score -5):

Think of {∅} as a box containing an empty box, then
{{∅}} is a box containing a box which contains an empty box, in which case
{{∅}} is box containing {∅}, which means

{∅} is subset of {{∅}}

Comment: :) I know ... just having fun

Comment: I think your analogy leads to: $$\{∅\} \text{ is an element of } \{\{∅\}\}.$$ A subset is equivalent to opening the bigger box, removing some of the contents (possibily all or none) and then closing it again. So, like other $1$ element sets, $\{\{∅\}\}$ has only two possible subsets: itself or the empty set.