# Is "{x}" or "x" a member of the set {x,y,z}?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm getting a little confused with sets and subsets.
Which of the following is a member of {x,y,z}?
"x" or {x}?

Comment: {x} is a member of {{x},{y},{z}}

Comment: $x$ is. $\{x\}$ is not (it is a subset of $\{x,y,z\}$ (relation $\subseteq$), not an element (relation $\in$)).

Comment: Informally, $\alpha$ is a member of a set $A=\{\cdots\}$ iff $\alpha$ is somewhere written exactly as it is in $\cdots$.

Comment: Also {x} is a subset of {x,y,z}

Comment: The dual question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491465/is-emptyset-a-subset-of-emptyset/491468#491468

Comment: Thanks. Would that mean that {x} is not member of {{x,y}}?

Comment: Indeed, it is not.

Comment: $x$ is a member of the set, $(x)$ is it self a set so it cannot be a member of your set $(x,y,z)$ unless your sets is comprises $((x),(y),(z))$.

Comment: see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064663/x-in-x-or-not/1064730#1064730)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the set $\{x,y,z\},$
we say that $x$ is a member of the set.

It is also true that $\{x\}$ is a *subset* of the set $\{x,y,z\}.$

---

**Addendum:** A set *can* be a member of another set.
For example, $\{x\}$ is a member of the set $\{\{x\},y,z\}.$
But in that case, observe the extra $\{\cdot\}$ brackets around $x$
that do not appear in the notation for the set $\{x,y,z\}.$
The sets $\{\{x\},y,z\}$ and $\{x,y,z\}$ are two quite different sets.

Comment: But would {x} be a subset of {{x},{y},{z}}?

Comment: In that case, it is a member. See other comments.

Comment: @Xenidious It is not a subset, since $x$ is not a member of $\{\{x\},\{y\},\{z\}\}$, i.e. it is not the case that all the members of $\{x\}$ are in $\{\{x\},\{y\},\{z\}\}$. By definition, $A\subseteq B\iff (x\in A\implies x\in B)$.