# Intersection of a non-empty collection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My textbook, *Mathematical Analysis For Machine Learning and Data Mining* by Dan Simovici, says the following:

> If $\mathcal{C}$ is a *non-empty* collection, its *intersection* is the set $\bigcap \mathcal{C}$ given by
>
> $$\bigcap \mathcal{C} = \{x \mid x \in S \ \ \text{for every $S \in \mathcal{C}$} \}$$

[Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NonemptySet.html) defines a **nonempty set** as follows:

> A nonempty set is a set containing one or more elements. Any set other than the empty set $\emptyset$ is therefore a nonempty set.

But, given these definitions, would it not be true that the intersection of any non-empty collection is the empty set? After all, the empty set is an element of every set ([including itself](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/334876/356308)), which means that, despite the fact that $\mathcal{C}$ itself is a non-empty set (that is, $\mathcal{C} \not= \emptyset$), all of the sets it contains *do* themselves contain the empty set as an element, and so we would always have that $x = \emptyset$ in the above definition?

I would appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: The empty set is **not** an *element* of every set, but a *subset* of every set.

Comment: Distinguish between the relations *being an element of* and the relation *is a subset of*. The empty set *is a subset of* every set, including itself.

Comment: You’re both right. Confusing “element of” and “subset of” was what confused me. Thank you both for the clarification.

Comment: No; let the collection $\mathcal C = \{ \{ 1,2,3 \}, \{ 1,2 \} \}$. The intersection of the collection is not the empty set.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA you’re right. Thanks again.