# Is the empty set a superset of itself?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know the empty set is a subset of itself, so I'm assuming that it's also the case that it is a superset of itself?

∅ ⊇ ∅

Comment: This is a great question..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the empty set a subset of itself?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334666/is-the-empty-set-a-subset-of-itself)

Comment: Yes.  $A \subseteq B \iff B\supseteq A$ so .... $\emptyset \subseteq \emptyset \iff \emptyset\supseteq \emptyset$..... Furthermore 1: Everyset is a subset and a superset of itself 2: The empty set is a subset of every set.  And 2: every set is a superset of the emptyset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. In the same way that every set is a superset of itself, but not a *proper* superset.

Comment: And the same way that every set is a superset of the empty set.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  $A \subseteq B \iff B\supseteq A$ so .... $\emptyset \subseteq \emptyset \iff \emptyset\supseteq \emptyset$

..... Furthermore

1. Every set is a subset and a superset of itself.  Or in other words $A \subseteq A$ and $A\supseteq A$ for all sets $A$. (This holds true even if $A$ is the empty set.)
2. The empty set is a subset of every set. Or in other words $\emptyset \subseteq A$ for all sets $A$. (This holds true even if $A$ is the empty set.)  And
3. Every set is a superset of the empty set. or in other words $A \supseteq \emptyset$ for all sets $A$. (This holds true ev.... well, you know the drill.)